# A challenge with onclick occured while combining MVC4, SignalR, knockoutJS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, signalr

I have a simple **MVC4** app where however I want to combine **knockoutJS** and **SignalR** and I got a challenge which seems to be caused by the fact that I'm trying to assign 2 onclick events on the same button: using knockoutJS and signalR. Please let me know what's wrong here. Below is the code.

This is my viewModel:

```
var viewModel = {
  searchString: ko.observable("Monique"),
  search: function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: "@Url.Action("Search")",
      type: "post",
      data: ko.toJSON(this),
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: function (result) {
        $('#info').append(result.message);
      }
    });
  },
  searchClient: function () {
    //do sth
  },
  showAll: function () {
    //do sth 
  }
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

And this part is related to signalR:

This is my hub on a server:

```
[HubName("send")]
public class DataHub: Hub
{
    public void Send(string text)
    {
        Clients.All.addMessage(text);
    }
}
```

and this is a signalR js part:

```
$(function () {
  var hub = $.connection.send;
  hub.client.addMessage = function (text) {
    alert(text);
    $('#info').append(text);
  };
  $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    $('#btnServer').click(function () {
      alert('btn server clicked');
      hub.server.send("something");
    });
  });
});
```

So as you can see, knockoutJS has onclick event processing here `search: function () { }`
and in signalR I also have `$('#btnServer').click(function() {`.

And as a result, what is related to knockoutJS works but the part related to signalR does not work...

Answer (score 0):

In that function where you bind click event using knockout, return `true`. By default, Knockout will prevent the click event from taking any default action.

Comment: It does not help...it seems that $('#btnServer').click(function() is never called..

Comment: Is 'done' called? It's hard to give advice without seeing HTML.